# Python - check if condition is met within a given timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a script that 1. downloads & push binaries to internal registry (func_to_push_image) and
2. process messages from a section of messaging queue, to see if the push is successful by filtering the messages for a keyword 3. If the push is successful, monitor and process another section of messaging queue, to validate whether those two binaries are installed by looking at the install_status keyword.

Timeout for the push action is 2 mins, else fail the script immediately. Timeout for the install action is 1 min, else fail the script with timeout.

Messaging queue's output for the binaries installations looks like below.

```
{
"location": "root",
"md5":"a3288ec45c8d159fbb656972eb4cdfg84jsfbsdf",
"fireEye":"v3",
"Binaries":[
A:{
"name":"HP-Protect",
"version": "v1.3",
"effect": "NIL",
"install_status":"On Going",
}
B:{
"name":"Covertur",
"version": "v1.0",
"effect": "NIL",
"install_status":"Installed"
}]
}
```

Redacted code:

```
registry_timeout = 2
install_timeout = 1
Other variables holding server and partition details.

def get_info_from_messaging_queue(server, broker):
    depending on the partition, returns the messages from the messaging queue.

def func_to_push_image():
    logic to upload the artifact to the registry.

def func_to_check_status_of_installed_binaries():  #This function should Ideally check the status of both binaries has been "Completed"
    status = False
    install_status = get_info_from_messaging_queue(server, broker)
    if install_status['Binaries'][A]['install_status'] == "Completed" and install_status['Binaries'][B]['install_status'] == "Completed":
            status = True
    return status
    
    
# to check if image is pushed within 2 minutes.
def timeout_verify_push_status():
    start = datetime.now()
    stop = start + timedelta(minutes=registry_timeout)
    while True:
        push_status = func_to_push_image()
        if push_status:
            break
        start = datetime.now()
        if start > stop_time:
            print("Timed Out while pushing image to registry...")
            break


# to check if installation is complete within a minute..
def timeout_verify_installation_status()():
    start = datetime.now()
    stop = start + timedelta(minutes=install_timeout)
    while True:
        install_status = func_to_check_status_of_installed_binaries()
        if install_status:
            break
        start_time = datetime.now()
        if start_time > stop_time:
            print("Timeout while installtion of Binaries...")
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    timeout_verify_push_status()
    timeout_verify_installation_status()
```

This gets the job done, it timeouts if the status is not Completed with in a minute, but it isn't efficient and I tried to handle the timeout condition using a single function but failed. How efficiently can it be handled ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a threadPoolExecutor or a processPoolExecuor:

```
    registry_timeout = 2
    install_timeout = 1
    Other variables holding server and partition details.
    
    def get_info_from_messaging_queue(server, broker):
        depending on the partition, returns the messages from the messaging queue.
    
    def func_to_push_image():
        logic to upload the artifact to the registry.
    
    def func_to_check_status_of_installed_binaries():  #This function should Ideally check the status of both binaries has been "Completed"
        status = False
        install_status = get_info_from_messaging_queue(server, broker)
        if install_status['Binaries'][A]['install_status'] == "Completed" and install_status['Binaries'][B]['install_status'] == "Completed":
                status = True
        return status

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            push_task = execuor.submit(func_to_push_image)
            install_task = executor.submit(func_to_check_status_of_installed_binaries)
            push_status = push_task.result(timeout=120)
            install_status = install_task.result(timeout=120)
```